# About class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, static

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyStaticClass{
public:
    static int value;
    MyStaticClass(){ 
        value++; 
    }
    ~MyStaticClass(){}
};
int MyStaticClass::value;
void main(){
    MyStaticClass::value = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<9; i++)
        MyStaticClass *c = new MyStaticClass();
    cout << MyStaticClass::value;
    system("pause");
}
```

Please explain me why the result is 9, and when replace `MyStaticClass *c = new MyStaticClass()` with `MyStaticClass c()` the result changes to 0? Finally what is the meaning of `int MyStaticClass::value;`, why when i delete that line the compiler shows error? Thanks everyone!

Comment: Reading your question and your comment, I think you should read a good introduction book about c++ (Thinking in c++ it is a good start and it is freely available on line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `int MyStaticClass::value;` tells the compiler to reserve storage for the `static` variable `value`. If you don't do that then the *linker* will fail.

The result is 9 since the `for` loop body executes 9 times: you are creating 9 new instances of `MyStaticClass` (which isn't really a `static` class, it just has a `static` member). Note that you ought to `delete` all these objects else your program leaks memory.

`MyStaticClass c();` declares a function *prototype* for a *function* `c` that takes no parameters and returns a `MyStaticClass`: it does **not** create an object. This is nicknamed the *most vexing parse*. Since no object is created, `value` stays at 0. It would have been a different matter had you written `MyStaticClass c;`

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer! Please explain me the meaning of the line `int MyStaticClass::value;`

Comment: I tried `MyStaticClass c`, the result was still 9. So why when we use pointer it creates object? I mean it still has `()`?

Comment: Yup. That's the thing about the *most vexing parse*. When using `new`, you do indeed need the parentheses. But when you don't use `new`, you shouldn't.